# How to send PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests in thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

How can I send a `DELETE` request with `thymeleaf`?
I tried as follows:

```
<form action="" th:method="delete">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href="/person/123" value="Delete" />
</form>

@RequestMapping(value="/person/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public String delete(@PathVariable String id) {
    personService.delete(id);
    return "Successfully deleted";
}
```

But all that I get is: `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported`

Comment: No. What spring does behind the scenes is adding a hidden method field, and posting an additional hidden parameter `_method=delete` during the `POST` request. Spring should normally resolve it accordingly to the `RequestMethod.DELETE`, but not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot 2.2+, you need to enable support for this explictly. Add the following to `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

Spring Boot < 2.2 always registers the filter, for Spring Boot 2.2 or higher you need to set the property.

Tip: You can replace `@RequestMapping(value="/person/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)` with `@DeleteMapping("/person/{id}")`

Comment: Is there any drawback enabling this feature? Why has it been disabled at all?

Comment: I believe it's because of the performance. It takes a significant amount of time just for doing this. You can check this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16953#issuecomment-497026795